# WP7 Policy Check

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to upload an application to the Windows Phone Marketplace but it keeps failing due to the location privacy policy. In the application there is only one part that checks your location, and the user has to manually call it. Basically we show a map, and a button to locate the user, when this button is pressed for the first time, we show a small privacy policy, and we ask the user to allow the use of his location. And even with this, the application's certification failed.

I'm wondering if anyone has a good example of how the privacy policy should be, and if it should be displayed when the app is first launched, rather than when the locations services are activated by the user (like we are currently doing it). And any other tips or advice you may have.

This is the only part of the certification the app failed, so once I get some good answers, it'll be ready to go.

Thanks!

Comment: What were the coments in the failure report?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to read the [Windows Phone 7 Application Certification Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Section 2.10 specifically applies to your problem.

Microsoft really wants you to have a permanent link to your privacy policy somewhere in the app.  Your privacy policy should explicitly explain that you collect this data, how you use it, how you store it, who you share it with, and what the user can do about it.  You also need a setting somewhere for the user to turn use of GeoLocation data off.

In my app I have an About screen with a link to the PrivPol, TOS and Tech Support.  I also have a settings page with an ON / OFF switch for GeoLocation data.  I made sure our privacy policy explicitly addresses location data.  And we got through approval with no issues.

YMMV.

Comment: He's looking for an example, not a link to the cert requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the specific certification requirement (the reference number) ? Here are a couple of links about it in the Windows Phone 7 developers forum:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/72366/441401.aspx#441401

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/63656/390088.aspx#390088